# why does my column go down?

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, grid, percentage

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMLLwB

```
    #news {
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#news ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#worldMap img {
    width: 100%;
}

.newspiece {
    margin-bottom: 2.5%;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #90C3D4;
    height: 130px;
}

.newspiece h3 {
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media(min-width: 600px) {
    .newspiece {
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

  .newspiece:first-child {
    margin-left:0;
  }
}
```

Am i missing something here? the width the total container (#news) is 85%, the width of each item is 25%, and two of them have a 5% left margin, total sums to 85%, then why  do i resize it, the rightmost column goes down?

Comment: you forgot the 20px padding. at some point the total width of the 3 blocks exceeds the width of the container, so the rightmost block gets wrapped to a new line.

Comment: I would take a look at how various CSS frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/) accomplish columns and rows as you are attempting to do. Doing so will help solve your current problem and some potential future problems I see coming.

Answer (score 1):

i have changed your html/css. this is a cleaner solution and is suported among all browsers

**html:**

```
 <div class="flex">
  <div class="box">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
   <div class="box">
     <h3>Title</h3>
    <img src="http://www.placecage.com/400/300" alt="">
  </div>
   <div class="box">
     <h3>Title</h3>
     <p>Content</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #90C3D4;
}

.box h3 {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

.box img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. Is flex commonly supported? ive never heard of it. ill tryr it and get back to you with the result

Answer (score 0):

`* { box-sizing: border-box; }`

The padding adds to the total width of the element if `box-sizing: border-box` is not used.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I assume all this does is calculate the element size together with the padding. After adding it, for some reason, it is cut on the bottom side of the element

Comment: @CakeToppings it might be because you have the `height` property of `.newspiece` and `overflow: hidden`.

You can try using `overflow: scroll` with the `height: 130px` or just use `height: auto`.